# resizing an iFrame in a Vue component each time frame content changes

Tags: vue.js, iframe, postmessage

I have a parent Vue component that renders an iframe which loads a child Vue component. When the user interacts with the child component it may load/reload another child component into the iframe.

I want to adjust the size of the iframe whenever it's content changes.

So I decided that when the current child hits the `onMounted()` hook it fires a signal to the parent (using `postMessage`).

The parent then queries the size of the document in the iframe and resizes the iframe to fit the content.

The problem I seem to be having is that the resize happens before the content is fully rendered, so the iframe is often the wrong size. If I set a 200 millisecond timeout it's fine.

Does this mean that onMounted() fires before the page is fully rendered? Any solutions to this?

The parent component:

```
<script setup>

import { usePostMessage }  from '@/composables/usePostMessage';
import { ref } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps({
        src : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        id : {
            type: String,
        }
    });

    const frame = ref(null);
    const isLoading = ref(true);

    const methods = {

        //adjust the iframe to fit the content
        resizeFrame(){
            const iframe = frame.value;
            if (iframe) {

                const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                iframe.style.height = iframeDocument.body.offsetHeight + "px";
                console.log('iframe size: ' + iframe.style.height)

            }
        },
        onLoaded(){
            isLoading.value=false;
        }
    };

    //listen to events from the iframe
    const {  listenToPostMessage } = usePostMessage();

    listenToPostMessage(['mounted'],methods.onLoaded);
    listenToPostMessage(['resizeFrame'],methods.resizeFrame);

</script>

<template>

    <div v-if="isLoading">
        <slot name="loading" />
    </div>

    <iframe :src="src" ref="frame" class="w-full h-0" :id="id"></iframe>


</template>
```

In each child component:

```
    onMounted(() => {
        postMessageFromIframe({action:'resizeFrame'});

    });
```

Comment: There may be no single point for "the content is fully rendered". In a simple scenario it may be enough to have nextTick inside onMounted. It's unknown which is the point in your case, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to investigate it.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks so much for your reply. Oh wow, this is embarrassing, but it turns out I had a async call to load an image from cloudinary which was increasing height slightly when it loaded. I've now set the height before the image loads and the problem has gone away. Sorry to waste your time!